# How is javac -sourcepath relating to the path of the file specified?

Tags: java, javac

I have this java source file

`C:\crp\dfdf\src\oata\HelloWorld.java`

I can compile it

`C:\crp\dfdf>javac -sourcepath c:\crp\dfdf -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.j
ava`

into

`C:\crp\dfdf\build\classes\oata\HelloWorld.class`

But I notice that (keeping the same directory and keeping the same other parameters as above) then whatever the sourcepath is, it still works

```
C:\crp\dfdf>javac -sourcepath c:\sdklsdlewrrblahthisdirdoesnotexist -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.java

C:\crp\dfdf>
```

And if I correct the sourcepath (so, back to `c:\crp\dfdf\src`) but move to a different directory, then it doesn't work

```
C:\>javac -sourcepath c:\crp\dfdf\src -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.java
javac: file not found: src\oata\HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

C:\>
```

I thought maybe the path of the file specified appends to the sourcepath, but this doesn't work either

```
C:\>javac -sourcepath c:\crp\dfdf\src -d build\classes oata\HelloWorld.java
javac: file not found: oata\HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

So i'm having trouble seeing how sourcepath is operating

Answer (score 3):

The `-sourcepath` is used when *other* files that may need compiling as dependencies aren't located where you would expect under the current directory or in relation to the source path of the file you specified to compile. It's rarely used.

Comment: could you give a simple example? so a java file with a dependency such that -sourcepath would be used and makes a difference.. so I could see what it looks like?   ta

Comment: Looks like -cp / -classpath, does too pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wB17PFEM  


pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wB17PFEM